# Remove IP Address from IP Security <ipSecurity> IIS8.0

Tags: iis

I am using iis 8.0 and trying to remove any allowed/restricted ip address from the list, screen shot is attached. i have used the remove variable by following [this link](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/applicationpooldefaults/environmentvariables?showTreeNavigation=true).

[image: IIS Screen Shot]

```
        var websiteName = "abc.com";
            using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
                var ipSecuritySection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity", websiteName);
                var ipSecurityCollection = ipSecuritySection.GetCollection();

                var addElement = ipSecurityCollection.CreateElement("remove");
                addElement["ipAddress"] = ipAddress;
                ipSecurityCollection.Remove(addElement);
                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
```

Guide me am i doing wrong, if yes? then what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to remove entry from the collection.

```
 var websiteName = "abc.com";
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
            var ipSecuritySection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity", websiteName);
            var ipSecurityCollection = ipSecuritySection.GetCollection();

            var addElement = ipSecurityCollection.CreateElement("remove");
            addElement["ipAddress"] = ipAddress;
            ipSecurityCollection.add(addElement);
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
```

Every thing was alright only one thing was wrong in the 2nd last line.

> ipSecurityCollection.remove(addElement);

Change it to

> ipSecurityCollection.add(addElement);

After that it will work perfectly.